# Combine and export multiple text areas?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a novice at javascript and was wondering if there is any way to combine the contents of several s into a single textarea in a new window?

I have a document in which the user currently has to copy/paste the contents of different textareas individually. I would like them to have the option of clicking a button to generate this.

I looked through this forum and managed to get close using:

```
<input type="button" value="combine" onclick="document.getElementById('textarea3').value=document.getElementById('textarea2').value+' '+document.getElementById('textarea3').value" />
```

However, I've only been successful in combining these two textareas to another textarea on the same page. I'm not able to combine this onclick event with a newWindow function to generate a clean page with the intended text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the value of combined textarea to some persistent variable. I will suggest to use localStorage. Here is some example:

First Page

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function combine(){
    // store your text to localStorage when someone click the link
    var textToPass=document.getElementById('textarea2').value+' '+document.getElementById('textarea3').value;
    localStorage.setItem("myText", textToPass);
}

</script>
<a onclick="combine()" href="secondPage.html" id="link">Go to second page</a>
```

On second page put this script block at the bottom of body

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var myText = localStorage.getItem("myText");
document.getElementById('textarea3').value = myText;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks John, I'll try that out and let you know how it worked.

Comment: Worked great. I didn't understand the localStorage property, so I'll try to learn more about it. Added the target="_blank" to the anchor to open in a new window.